# Why Pandas does not read xlsx files?

Tags: excel, pandas

I am having trouble reading an xlsx file on Pandas.. The same code used to work before but does not work anymore. I tried a lot of ways but to no avails.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv("Muzika.xlsx")
print(df)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is not `.csv`, it is an excel file, so try `read_excel()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html